# 'npm <script-command>' NOT working. Changes to npm run-script <script-command>

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I am setting up a node js backend to run off TS for the first time in a mono-repo with a folder structure like so.
[image: backend folder structure like so]

My package.json is in the root directory below:

```
   "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject",
      "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q backend/index.js\""
  },
```

before using concurrently and TS, I could just execute `npm dev` and it would start my servers.

Now I have to type npm run-script dev. Why is this? It's no bother, but I'm just curious, where and how one would change this if needed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run dev` Is the shortest (*current*) option :)

Comment: so when I executed that, it would not even run. I would get a message. showing npm commands I could use.